# The probability he will get the point $n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is a line with $n+1$ points($0,1,2...n$).At the beginning,a man standing in the point $0$. He will go forward with the probability $p$ (and backward with $1-p$),If he's position $<0$ or $=n$,the game is over.
 What's the probability he will get the point $n$ ?

Comment: This is like a Random Walk. Consider all the paths/choices that lead to the point $n$ and to the point $0$, and find the respective probabilities.

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial

Comment: @aaa Not sure this is related.

Comment: @user99680 Did you try to use your own suggestion?

Comment: No, not formally, why; do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @user99680 You realize you might be sending the OP in a morass of unconclusive computations, by not checking they work? And actually this is exactly what you are doing here, hence, if I may, let me suggest more caution with your hints. (Unrelated: please use @.)

Comment: @Did: I don't see what's wrong; I'm trying to construct the set of paths that lead to n and assign a probability to this set of outcomes. What's inconclusive about this? And, besides, aren't hints supposed to be more "cautious"than actual claims and answers? So we consider the path where we go directly to n; in n steps with probability $p^n$ , then we consider what happens when we go back once, twice, etc. before hitting n. What's so bad about this approach: all paths with , respectively, 0,1,..,n-3 steps back, all other steps forward?

Comment: @user99680 About the maths: first, the estimation of the sum of the probabilities of the paths you mention is not so simple (once again, did you do it?), second, the lengthes of the paths one must count are not bounded by 2n-3 hence you forgot some. On the mention of a "hint": the way I understand it and the way I see it used on the site, a "hint" is NOT only a vague idea related to the question which might or might not lead to a solution. A hint is a precise direction one points the OP to because one knows for sure that following this direction will lead the OP to a full proof.

Comment: I did not say that the lengths are bounded; I referred to the number of returns in the path, where a return means going from k to k-1, and there can be at most n-1 returns, and these must happen in specific ways. And I'm sorry to disagree with you; I don't know if others agree with me or not, or if this is governed by some rules, but a hint is an idea; I have thought it through, maybe enot to the point of having an actual solution, but the OP also has a responsibility to double-check. And if someone convinces me that my approach has no merits, then I will either delete my comment, or post a

Comment: Disclaimer. I need to practice; it benefits me, but I also make an effort to consider feedback so that I don't do it at other's expense. Besides, why do you chide me more than you did aaa, who also gave a hint you consider not to be useful? How about the hundreds of hints in other questions that are flat wrong? Still, it may be more constructive if we could post this in "Meta"

Comment: @user99680 "there can be at most n-1 returns" No, there can be as many -1 steps as one wants. This is one of the two (already stated) reasons why your suggestion does not work. (But **please use @** if you want to be read.)

Comment: @Did : Sorry for not using @. You're right, I did miss that part. So I did learn somethingIn general, don't you think the fact that there are so many users here makes it unlikely for someone to be misled, given someone--like you in this case--will put my suggestion into question?

Comment: @user99680 No I do not think that (but I think we are much too far from the question asked on this page).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for every $-1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, consider the probability $u(k)$ to reach $n$ before $-1$, starting from $k$. Then $u(-1)=0$, $u(n)=1$ and, for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$, $u(k)$ is a simple linear combination of $u(k-1)$ and $u(k+1)$. Solve the linear system and deduce $u(0)$.

You will need to know that the recursion $x_k=ax_{k-1}+bx_{k+1}$ is solved by $x_k=C_1r_1^k+C_2r_2^k$ for some constants $C_1$ and $C_2$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ solve the characteristic equation $r=a+br^2$.